# React native - SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, windows, react-native

When running `react-native start`, I get the following error:

```
c:\app\node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\Server\index.js:549
      ),
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (c:\app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:166:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (buildBundle.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
```

This is on Windows 10, running node v6.2.1 and npm v3.9.3. I am running the latest version of `react-native`, 0.26.3.

This happens every time I run `react-native`, also for `init` and `run-android`.

This seems to be an issue with Babel on windows, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is that your file `Server\index.js` ?

Comment: No, it is from inside the `react-native` library.

Comment: The app is just the hello world app from `react-native`.